# Regex for check letter in any position

Tags: regex, expression

this few hours i have been "fighting" with this case.I am trying to check if a car plate is valid (in my country it is like this **99-KL-99**).

The plate has 4 simple rules:

- Can only have(and must have) 2 Letters
- Can only have(and must have) 4 numbers
- Must have two "-"
- Max range is 9

The letters or numbers can be random like "9F-P2-12" OR "99-JM-99" and i was trying to get a regex as simple as possible without the OR condition if possible and so far i got this two examples wich i just need a little improvement to get where i want to

1st:

```
 ^^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1}-[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1}-[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1}$
```

Which matches something like this "a1-b1-c1" or "E4-A1-E8", but what if i want to check if it has the letter and number no matter what position? And how can i control the rule of 4 numbers and 2 letters?

2nd

```
 ^(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)
```

Which matches something like "123", "321", etc. No matter what position they are it matches, and this is kinda what i want.

I just need to work with this, and i have been trying many regex expressions and still not getting what i need.

EDIT:

Now i got this :

```
^(\w\w)-(\w\w)-(\w\w)$
```

which works perfectly but is it possible to add one "AND" operator? something like

> ^(\w\w)-(\w\w)-(\w\w)$ AND 4 numbers? AND 2 letters?

Comment: That should work -  [`^(?=(?:\D*\d){4}\D*$)(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2}[^a-zA-Z]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}){2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xU6oJ1/1). Not as simple as you might want though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its does not seem to work mate, tryed with "99-hm-99" and "jm-00-22"

Comment: ... and [they get matched well](https://regex101.com/r/xU6oJ1/2), right?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Code? Its just a simple regex there is no code here and i shared already what i got so far. Thank you

Comment: Thank me for what? You say it is "not working", but "not working" says nothing to me, nor to anyone else. I showed you it is matching your input, now, I would like to understand how I can help you make it match the same on your side. How can I help if I do not know details? And: do not use `\w` as it matches `_`, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d.*){4})(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){2})[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:-[A-Z0-9]{2}){2}$
```

In which:

```
^                               <= ensure start of string
 (?=(?:.*\d.*){4})              <= ensure that there is at least 4 digits
 (?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){2})           <= ensure that there is at least 2 alpha
 [A-Z0-9]{2}(?:-[A-Z0-9]{2}){2} <= specifies the format
$                               <= ensure end of string
```

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH7jN3/1)

Answer (score -1):

After taking a look at your comments and suggestions i finally got it, in a simple way

```
(?=.*(\w\w)-(\w\w)-(\w\w)$)(?=(?:.*\d.*){4})(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){2})
```